# How do i get result in box in current window through express node after click on submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, express

I am unable to get a response with node and express when i click the submit button. I am fairly new to node and express. Here is what I have tried. Can you tell me what is wrong with my code? Please guide me on how to get instantaneous response in the box on current html or what is other way to get response instead of async function?

```
<p class="borderBox"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing all of your code. But I think the first issue is that you aren't checking your req.headers kvps defensively enough. Certain headers are not always present in a request, so you'll need to provide for the case where they don't arrive as expected

```
     if (req['x-forwarded-for']) {
         var ip = req['x-forwarded-for'].split(',')
```

or

```
     req['x-forwarded-for'] = req['x-forwarded-for'] || ''
```

**UPDATE**

Judging by what code you have provided, first make the following changes to your server.js code:

```
app.get('/headers', function(req, res) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'])
        var ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"].split(',')[0];
    if (req.headers['accept-language'])
        var lang  = req.headers['accept-language'].split(',')
    if (req.headers['user-agent'])
        var sys = req.headers['user-agent'].match(/\((.+?)\)/)[1]


    var obj = {
        "IP Address": ip,
        "Language" : lang,
        "Operating System": sys
    }

    // res.json(obj);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(200).send(obj);
});
```

Then, you have to make a change to the URI you call with `fetch()` so it reaches the endpoint you've specified above in your `app.get()` (i.e. '/headers'). I'm using localhost on port 3000.

```
$("#submit").submit(async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // const response = await fetch(window.location.href);
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/headers');
    const data = await response.json();
    document.getElementsByClassName('borderBox')[0].innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

Finally, I don't know much about your project setup, but here's how I did it by serving an index.html file from express using

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and placing `index.html` in a directory named `/public` at the root directory of the express app. The file `index.html` is below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>
    Please click to get the IP address, language, and operating system for your 
device.
</p>

<form id="submit">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


<p class="borderBox">    </p>

<script>
    $("#submit").submit(async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // const response = await fetch(window.location.href);
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/headers');
        const data = await response.json();
        document.getElementsByClassName('borderBox')[0].innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
    });
</script>
```

I'm just including this last part because, again, I can't see how you've set up your project - but this worked for me.

Comment: I edited it at your suggestion but the result still does not come in the box.

Comment: Like I said, without seeing all of the code, it's hard to say. For instance, you use a jquery submit event trigger but you have no form elements on the page. That won't work. Try $("#submit").on('click', => (ev) { ... })

Comment: Thank for replying. It says that $("#submit").on('click', => (ev) { ... })  throws parsing error.  Can you resend correct code statement?

Comment: I edited it to form element on the page, but it still does not work.

Comment: perhaps you can host this somewhere so people can help debug your issue, like @elight said, without code there isnt a whole lot we can do to help..

Comment: Anyone care to help debug this issue?

Comment: @DGRFDSGN, are you there?